# How do you push a string with inline assembly

Tags: string, assembly, push

I know you can simply do

`char msg[] = "lol";
_asm { push msg }`

But is there a way to do it in the assembly part?

`_asm { push "lol" }` This comes up with a compiler error

I'm a beginner, be nice :P

Comment: Platform/Architecture/Compiler?

Comment: You can't declare variables in C++ inline assembly.

Answer (score 1):

```
call @F
db 'lol',0
@@:
```

That's how you'd do it in MASM, not sure of the exact syntax for inline assembly. But there is one big difference. The first method stores the "lol" string in the data section of the exe, whereas the inline version stores it in the code section. For a few strings it's not that big a deal.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in visual c++? "error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found 'constant'"

Comment: You can't use MASM directives in inline assembler. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h70hd396(VS.71).aspx